# Metaprogramming, wrong number of template arguments

Tags: c++

I am trying C++ metaprogrammation. I have a TypeList class which contain a head type and a tail type which is another TypeList or the NullType at the end of the list.

I also have a IntegerList class which is a list of pointers on Integers (Well, it was a logging system, but I deleted as much code as I could, and Integer* elements replaced Logger* elements)

My file won't compile as g++ complains that I am using a "wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)", and I don't understand why.

Where did I do wrong ? I just copied some code from a website I trust, it should work... I mostly decided to use meta-programming because it seemed to be a pretty interresting thing to do, but I am begining to loose my mind already ^^.

Thank you in advance.

PS. I have a pretty old g++ compiler that I cannot change (2006), but another g++ from 2013 gave me the same error.

PS2. I think that this cold wouldn't compile because Integer is not a class, but I get the same error with a real class, so I believe that my error happen before this is checked.

IntegerList.hpp :

```
#include <list>

typedef int Integer;

class NullType
{
};

template<class H, class T>
class TypeList
{
    typedef H Head;
    typedef T Tail;
};

template<class T>
struct IntegerList : public std::list<Integer*>
{
};

template<>
struct IntegerList<NullType> : public std::list<Integer*>
{
};

template <class H, class T>
struct IntegerList<TypeList<typename H, typename T> > :  public std::list<Integer*>
{ //                                              ^ error right there
  typedef TypeList<typename H, typename T> List_t;
  typedef typename H Head_t;
  typedef typename T Tail_t;

  IntegerList()
  {
    push_back( new Head_t );
    IntegerList<Tail_t> tmp;
    merge( tmp );
  }

  ~IntegerList()
  {
    IntegerList<List_t>::iterator it;
    for ( it=begin(); it!=end(); ++it )
      delete *it;
  }
};
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "IntegerList.hpp"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{  
   // wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
  IntegerList<TypeList<Integer, NullType> > mylist;
}
```

Comment: What is your Error and why is TypeList simply a Class of types? (another Null class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you sprinkled a few too many `typename`s at the usage of `IntegerList` and `TypeList`. The following compiles:

```
template <class H, class T>
struct IntegerList<TypeList< H,  T> > :  public std::list<Integer*>
{ 
  typedef TypeList< H,  T> List_t;
  typedef H Head_t;
  typedef T Tail_t;
  . . .
}
```

Full example http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5086e3015dc12ea0

Comment: By the way, wherever you are with an 11 year old compiler you should consider leaving or demand an upgrade.

Comment: I have one that is from 2003  :-(